# jQuery: get value of visible element out of class

Tags: jquery, class, visible

I have a page with several HTML dropdowns.

All dropdowns have the same class and there is always only one of them visible on the page at a time (the others are hidden with jQuery based on different rules before).

How can I get only the value of the currently visible element out of this class ("myClass") ?

**Example dropdown:**

```
<select class="myClass" id="status1" name="status1">
    <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**:visible Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$('.myClass:visible').val()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/8B4Xk/)

Comment: @user2571510, Yep its simple. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Try with [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector of jQuery.

```
$('.myClass:visible')
```